# Posicionar una imagen sobre otra segun el ancho de la pantalla

Tags: html, css

Este es mi código y quisiera saber como hacer que la imagen 2.jpg quede arriba de la imagen 1.jpg, claro cuando la pantalla se reduzca.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
  <img src="img/1.jpg" class="float-left col-lg-6 col-sm-12" alt="ola" width="100%" height="236" style="padding: 0;"> 
  <img src="img/2.jpg" class="float-right col-lg-6 col-sm-12" alt="hey" width="100%" height="236" style="padding: 0;"> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Esto lo puedes lograr con los *media query* de css

Answer (score 0):

En tu hoja de estilos CSS puedes darle al div contenedor display: flex y flex-wrap: wrap-reverse para que se produzca eso.

Tú código debería verse así

```
.row {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
}
```

Ten en cuenta que las imagenes van a reordenarse dependiendo de su width y margin. Cuando ya no puedan mostrarse ambas en la pantalla una al lado de la otra.